# Iterating through array produced by MongoDB aggregation query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Good afternoon all,

I am having a really tough time working with aggregation queries in MongoDB 3.4. I have a problem that is asking me to do push the results of my aggregation query into an empty array called `categories` which I have been able to do successfully using this code:

```
var categories = [];

    database.collection("item").aggregate([{
        $group : {
            _id : "$category",
             num : {$sum : 1}
         }},
        {$sort:{_id:1}}]).toArray(function(err, data){

            categories.push(...data);
            callback(categories);
            console.log(categories);
        })

    }
```

`categories` looks like this:

```
[ { _id: 'Apparel', num: 6 },
{ _id: 'Books', num: 3 },
{ _id: 'Electronics', num: 3 },
{ _id: 'Kitchen', num: 3 },
{ _id: 'Office', num: 2 },
{ _id: 'Stickers', num: 2 },
{ _id: 'Swag', num: 2 },
{ _id: 'Umbrellas', num: 2 } ]
```

Next I have the following task:

> ```
>      In addition to the categories created by your aggregation query,
>      include a document for category "All" in the array of categories
>      passed to the callback. The "All" category should contain the total
>      number of items across all categories as its value for "num". The
>      most efficient way to calculate this value is to iterate through
>      the array of categories produced by your aggregation query, summing        
>      counts of items in each category.
> ```

The problem is that it seems like inside my `.toArray()` method the `data` parameter sometimes acts like an array and sometimes not. For example if I wanted to add perhaps just the value of the `num` key to the `categories` array like so: `categories.push(...data["num"])` I get an error stating `undefined is not iterable`.

Since I cannot iterate over each `data.num` key I cannot extract it's value and add it to a running total of all `data.num` values.

What am I not understanding about what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use application logic to group data, mongoDB aggregation is made for this task. Add another [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to your query with a new field `All` that [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) your `$num` field and [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) all documents to a new field called `categories` :

```
db.item.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$category",
        num: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}, { $sort: { _id: 1 } }, {
    $group: {
        _id: 1,
        All: { $sum: "$num" },
        categories: {
            $push: {
                _id: "$_id",
                num: "$num"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

It gives :

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "All": 23,
    "categories": [{
        "_id": "Swag",
        "num": 2
    }, {
        "_id": "Office",
        "num": 2
    }, {
        "_id": "Stickers",
        "num": 2
    }, {
        "_id": "Apparel",
        "num": 6
    }, {
        "_id": "Umbrellas",
        "num": 2
    }, {
        "_id": "Kitchen",
        "num": 3
    }, {
        "_id": "Books",
        "num": 3
    }, {
        "_id": "Electronics",
        "num": 3
    }]
}
```

For consuming the output, `data` is an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp), to access the first element use `data[0]` :

```
var categories = [];

database.collection("item").aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$category",
        num: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}, { $sort: { _id: 1 } }, {
    $group: {
        _id: 1,
        All: { $sum: "$num" },
        categories: {
            $push: {
                _id: "$_id",
                num: "$num"
            }
        }
    }
}]).toArray(function(err, data) {

    var totalCount = data[0]["All"];
    console.log("total count is " + totalCount);

    categories = data[0]["categories"];

    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        console.log("category : " + categories[i]._id + " | count : " + categories[i].num);
    }
})
```

Comment: Your solution is close to what I was looking for and I appreciate your response. I think overall after your input I have a better understanding of what I'm dealing with. The only thing I was not clear on was the need to make the new `{category: "All}` document part of the `data` array. I will post my answer below yours so you can see what I was going for.

Answer (score -1):

What I wanted to achieve was pushing or unshifting as we'll see in a moment an object that looked like this *into* my `categories` array:

```
var allCategory = {
      _id: "All",
      num: [sum of all data.num values]
}
```

I ended up messing with `.reduce()` method and used it on the `categories` array. I got lucky through some `console.log`-ing and ended up making this:

```
var categories = [];

    database.collection("item").aggregate([{
        $group : {
            _id : "$category",
             num : {$sum : 1}
         }},
        {$sort:{_id:1}}]).toArray(function(err, data){
            categories.push(...data);
            var sum = categories.reduce(function(acc, val){
                // console.log(acc, val["num"])
                return acc + val["num"]
            },0);

            var allCategory = {
                _id: "All",
                num: sum
            }
            categories.unshift(allCategory)
            callback(categories);
        })
```

First I use a spread operator to push all the objects from `data` into `categories`. Then declare `sum` which runs `.reduce()` on `categories` returning the accumulation of `val["num"]` which is really `data.num` (console log is life). I create the `allCategory` document/object then use `.unshift` to place it at the beginning of my `categories` array (this placement was a requirement) then use my callback.

I think it's a hacky way of accomplishing my goal and I had to go through some trial and error as to the correct order of methods and variables in my `.toArray()`. Yet it worked and I learned something. Thanks for the help @Bertrand Martel .